# После переноса сайта с сервера на сервер на Drupal не подключается к mySql

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, drupal

После переноса сайта с сервера на сервер на Drupal не подключается к mySql
В логах нового сервера вот такая ошибка не могу понять как решить.

2021/09/03 05:44:29 [error] 846#846: *102 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Error: Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/web-sites/sait/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php on line 402 #0 /var/www/web-sites/sait/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(371): Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection::open(Array)
#1 /var/www/web-sites/sait/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(166): Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection('default', 'default')
#2 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default')
#3 /var/www/web-sites/sait/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(79): call_user_func_array('Drupal\Core\Dat...', Array)
#4 /var/www/web-sites/sait/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(173): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'database')
#5 /var/www/web-sites/sait/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(265): Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Contain" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.58, server: 192.168.2.87, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.2.87"

Comment: похоже на сервере не установлено расширение php. Попробуйте что-то типа sudo apt install php8.0-mysql

Comment: Скорее [PHP-PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813381/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found)